# How to access pytest fixtures which reside in an included submodule?

Tags: python, git, testing, pytest, git-submodules

I have two repositories, repo A and repo B, and I want to use the same pytest fixture in both of these repos. Something like that:

```
# C/conftest.py

# fixture I want to share
@pytest.fixture
def normal_user():
    user = admin_client.create_user()
    yield user
    admin_client.delete_user(user)
```

For all shared code, I'm currently using some common repository C, which I include in both A and B as a submodule. My structure for A repository is like this:

```
A/C/conftest.py
A/C/some_shared_stuff.py
A/src/users.py
A/tests/test_users.py
```

However, if i run tests, the fixture from the submodule is not found by pytest.

```
E       fixture 'normal_user' not found
```

It seems like a standard behaviour, as stated in [docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#conftest-py-sharing-fixtures-across-multiple-files):

> [image]

> Tests are allowed to search upward (stepping outside a circle) for fixtures, but can never go down (stepping inside a circle) to continue their search. So tests/subpackage/test_subpackage.py::test_order would be able to find the innermost fixture defined in tests/subpackage/test_subpackage.py, but the one defined in tests/test_top.py would be unavailable to it because it would have to step down a level (step inside a circle) to find it.

and reading further...

> Fixtures don’t have to be defined in this structure to be available for tests, though. They can also be provided by third-party plugins that are installed, and this is how many pytest plugins operate. As long as those plugins are installed, the fixtures they provide can be requested from anywhere in your test suite.

But I wonder if there is a simpler way to use my fixtures from a submodule without having to create a whole new separate plugin?

I tried things like adding `C` directory to PYTHONPATH, or using pytest with `-p` flag to point to `C` directory, with no success.

Comment: This is an expected behavior. fixtures from conftest is available to the directory or the nested subdirectories of the location of conftest. In your circumstance, you can make your conftest an installable pytest plugin which can be accessed by other projects. Import conftest is not recommended. https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/writing_plugins.html

Comment: Another simpler workaround is to have conftest for both A and B. And, import shared content from C to the respective conftests.
A/C/conftest_contents.py
A/C/some_shared_stuff.py
A/src/users.py
A/tests/conftest.py
A/tests/test_users.py

In A/tests/conftest.py,  you can import functions from A/C/conftest_contents.py and make them into fixtures. 
It's a bit hacky.

Comment: Nice workaround, I basically can leave contents of my C/conftest.py file and just rename it to C/conftest_contents.py, and then do: `from C.conftest_contents import *` inside my A/conftest.py to be able to use all these shared fixtures.

Comment: `from C.conftest_contents import *` is not a recommended way to import fixtures. But you can give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

By default, all files will be shared at all repositories.

If you want to exclude a file from sharing in all repositories, just add it in the .gitignore file.

So just check your .gitignore file and remove **conftest.py**.

*Note: be careful when modifying the .gitignore file.*